# Phusion Passenger wants always to run bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, phusion

Phusion Passenger + Nginx
The web site worked fine for today. Today i updated my code, added my user for sudo group and run 'sudo bundle install' and 'touch tmp/restart.txt'. After that i saw 'bundle install error' - http://url.od.ua it still there

I tryed to run 'bundle install' from root user, but it nothing changed. 
It worked before! How i can fix it?

```
url.od.ua@server:~/web$ bundle install
Using rake 10.1.0
Using i18n 0.6.5
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.8.0
Using atomic 1.1.14
Using thread_safe 0.1.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.37
Using activesupport 4.0.0
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.0.0
Using mime-types 1.25
Using polyglot 0.3.3
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.0.0
Using activemodel 4.0.0
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Using arel 4.0.0
Using activerecord 4.0.0
Using coderay 1.0.9
Using coffee-script-source 1.6.3
Using execjs 2.0.1
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using thor 0.18.1
Using railties 4.0.0
Using coffee-rails 4.0.0
Using diff-lcs 1.2.4
Using exception_notification 4.0.1
Using factory_girl 4.2.0
Using factory_girl_rails 4.2.1
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using haml 4.0.3
Using hike 1.2.3
Using jbuilder 1.5.1
Using jquery-rails 2.3.0
Using json 1.8.0
Using libv8 3.16.14.3
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using mini_portile 0.5.1
Using mysql2 0.3.11
Using newrelic_rpm 3.6.6.147
Using nokogiri 1.6.0
Using slop 3.4.6
Using pry 0.9.12.2
Using bundler 1.6.1
Using sprockets 2.10.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.0.0
Using rails 4.0.0
Using rdoc 3.12.2
Using ref 1.0.5
Using rspec-core 2.14.5
Using rspec-expectations 2.14.2
Using rspec-mocks 2.14.3
Using rspec-rails 2.14.0
Using sape-rails 0.0.1 from git://github.com/hazg/sape-rails (at master)
Using sass 3.2.10
Using sass-rails 4.0.0
Using sdoc 0.3.20
Using therubyracer 0.12.1
Using turbolinks 1.3.0
Using uglifier 2.2.1
Using webrat 0.7.3
Using will_paginate 3.0.4
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
url.od.ua@server:~/web$ touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Comment: There is no `sudo bundle install`, Try `bundle install` only.

Comment: Did you install rvm ruby for the current user?

Comment: Please refer https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu and install it again

Comment: Spend a few moments now and install rvm , you will be thanking yourself later as it saves so much time . Rvm allows you to create specific gemsets for each project .

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot! I installed rvm, and all works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've referred this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu) and installed it again.

I installed rvm, and all works fine!